# matplotlib backend pgf version unknown

Tags: matplotlib, logging, xelatex, pgf

I'm getting a debug message from `matplotlib` with the `pgf` backend:

```
matplotlib.backends DEBUG backend pgf version unknown
```

My matplotlib setup is something like

```
mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
mpl.rcParams['pgf.rcfonts'] = False
mpl.rcParams['pgf.texsystem'] = 'xelatex'
mpl.rcParams["pgf.preamble"] = # xelatex fonts setup and other stuff
```

Is there a way to silent this message? maybe require a specific pgf version?

Comment: You seem to be in debug mode. Any idea how you got there? Did you activate it on purpose?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have logging enabled at application level, messages up to the info level go to console with a stream handler and full logs go to a file handler

Comment: I'm using the debug level for some of my detailed logs. Should I just filter out matplotlib messages some way?

Comment: Not sure what you *should* do. At the end you activated logging and you got that log message, which is desireable, is it not?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I could do `logging.getLogger("matplotlib.backends").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` but my main point was: is it something I should worry about?

Comment: No, nothing to worry about, I updated the answer.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! I was worried it was something wrong in my latex setup, glad to know I can safely ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to use logging, but not get any log messages from matplotlib you can do as [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#getting-help) states:

> Note that if you want to use logging in your own code, but do not want verbose Matplotlib output, you can set the logging level for Matplotlib independently:
>
> ```
> import logging
> # set DEBUG for everything
> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
> logger = logging.getLogger('matplotlib')
> # set WARNING for Matplotlib
> logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
> ```

Note that

```
matplotlib.backends DEBUG backend pgf version unknown
```

is a log message, not a warning. It's meant to tell you the version of the backend. However there is no version set for the pgf backend. This is nothing to worry about, unless you would need your application to know such version. In this case I would suggest to use the matplotlib version instead.

More in detail, backends can set a version. As in [backend_bases.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/ad44a7e413521336281469ff4569752c9eab180b/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L3226)

```
backend_version = "unknown"
```

this is "unknown" in general, but if a certain backend wants to set it, it may. The pgf backend, does not care to do so, which one could consider as a flaw in the code, but such version is usually not really required, as the default backends (like pgf) are part of matplotlib itself, such the matplotlib version itself should give you all needed information for your application.